# A biotechnology question involving probability.

Tags: probability

This question does require some basic knowledge of DNA.

Suppose I have a randomly generated sequence of 48,502 base pairs of nucleotides long. There are (of course) 4 nucleotides, A, C, T, and G. How would I calculate the probability that a specific 6 nucleotide long sequence would appear (When read 5' to 3': GAATTC, CCCGGG, AAGCTTT)?

Answer (score 1):

The strings you give as examples are all not self-overlapping; that is, if they occur in two positions, these positions must differ by at least $6$. For such strings, the probability can readily be calculated using inclusion-exclusion.

For a non-overlapping string of length $m$ to occur in $k$ particular positions in $n$ base pairs, there are $\binom{n-k(m-1)}k$ ways to choose the positions and $4^{n-km}$ ways to choose the remaining base pairs, so by inclusion-exclusion the probability for a sequence not to contain any occurrences of the string is

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac nm\right\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{n-k(m-1)}k4^{-km}\;.
$$

In your case, with $n=48502$ and $m=6$, this is

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\left\lfloor\frac{48502}6\right\rfloor}(-1)^k\binom{48502-5k}k4^{-6k}\approx6.9\cdot10^{-6}\;,
$$

and the probability of at least one occurrence is the complement, about $0.9999931$.

For self-overlapping strings, things are a bit more complicated, but still manageable.